# Internationalization in Java Error

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am learning Java, our teacher told us an internationalization example in netbeans, he created three properties file for different language ( in netbeans u can easily create properties file ), so i was trying this at home using eclipse, now i created 3 properties file exactly in the same folder our teacher created ( where .java files were ) 
i did the same code he did, but i got an error, then i tried to run the netbeans project ( which i took it from our teacher's computer ) in netbeans, it gave me the same error, now i think coding is fine but there is some error in properties file

here is the code

```
package example;


import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 156);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("My Internationalization Example");
        lbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lbl.setBounds(106, 21, 204, 17);
        contentPane.add(lbl);

        JRadioButton rdbtnEnglish = new JRadioButton("English");
        rdbtnEnglish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Locale lang = new Locale("en" , "US");
                ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/example/MessageBundle_en_US", lang);
                lbl.setText(message.getString("LangValue"));
            }
        });
        rdbtnEnglish.setBounds(42, 59, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnEnglish);

        JRadioButton rdbtnFrance = new JRadioButton("France");
        rdbtnFrance.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    Locale lang = new Locale("fr" , "FR");
                    ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/example/MessageBundle_fr_FR", lang);
                    lbl.setText(message.getString("LangValue"));
                }
        });
        rdbtnFrance.setBounds(153, 59, 142, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnFrance);

        JRadioButton rdbtnGerman = new JRadioButton("German");
        rdbtnGerman.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Locale lang = new Locale("de" , "DE");
                ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/example/MessageBundle_de_DE", lang);
                lbl.setText(message.getString("LangValue"));
            }
        });
        rdbtnGerman.setBounds(297, 59, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnGerman);


        ButtonGroup myGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        myGroup.add(rdbtnEnglish);
        myGroup.add(rdbtnFrance);
        myGroup.add(rdbtnGerman);

        rdbtnEnglish.setSelected(true);




    }

}
```

here is the stuff in all three properties file

MessageBundle_en_US.properties

```
LangValue = My Internationalization Example
```

MessageBundle_de_DE.properties

```
LangValue = Meine Internationalisierung Beispiel
```

MessageBundle_fr_FR.properties

```
LangValue = Mon internationalisation Exemple
```

now this is the folder where my properties and java file is

> D:\Documents\Work\Eclipse\InternationalizationExample\src\example

here is a screen shot for a better view

[image]

[image]

now when i run, my program runs, but when i select the options , it gives me this error which i googled for straight 3 hours and tried everything from changing the location, folders etc

[image]

and when i click the other option BOOM , i get an error

[image]

and the error is

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   src/example/MessageBundle_fr_FR, locale fr_FR     at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)    at
>   example.MyFrame$3.actionPerformed(MyFrame.java:75)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

for more help, i've upload my whole eclipse project into this rar

http://www.mediafire.com/download/yxnsrch41qhcxuw/InternationalizationExample.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your getBundle statements from:

```
ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/example/MessageBundle_en_US", lang);
```

to:

```
ResourceBundle message = ResourceBundle.getBundle("example/MessageBundle", lang);
```

Comment: worked !! THAAAANKSS !, can u elaborate a little why removed " src " from the path ?

p.s i remember now that our teacher told us to not write the language and country short form in the end, but why, can u explain?

Comment: Your very welcome!  Actually it doesn't hurt to put the locale info at the end, but it's not necessary since it will get that information from the `lang` parameter anyway. The reason to remove "src" is that the search for the bundle is done according to the classpath, the same way it finds .class files. The classpath includes the `src/` and `bin/` directories, so the names of classes and bundles start after that.

Comment: Since the resource bundle is in the same directory as the class, you can think of it as being in the `example` package. Just like the full name of the class is `example.MyFrame` (and not `src.example.MyFrame`), you search for the bundle with `example/MessageBundle` and not `src/example/MessageBundle`.